# How to fix a widget's position to not move while scrolling in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have made a custom drawer ui but I want the user details part of it and the logout button shouldn't be scrolling. I've used positioned but it gives incorrect parent usage and in stack separately on every single widget its not working how can I achieve static ui position I don't want to get the user details and logout button move as well with the scroll and also I don't want to lose responsiveness over different screen sizes.
[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot2]

```
import 'package:avunja/commons/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'onlinebutton.dart';

class InkWellDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InkWellDrawerState createState() => _InkWellDrawerState();
}

class _InkWellDrawerState extends State<InkWellDrawer> {
  bool _enable = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        color: Color(ReddishColor),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 80,
                        color: Color(0xFFBB0218),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 30.0,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        AssetImage("assets/girl.png"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 90, bottom: 40),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Angela Moury",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16),
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 90, top: 5),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "(254)7XX XX5 555",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: 14),
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 90, top: 45),
                                  child: Text("carrie.m@avunja.com",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Image.asset('assets/power.png'),
                          title: Text(
                            'Online Status',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          trailing: CustomSwitch(
                            value: _enable,
                            onChanged: (bool val) {
                              setState(() {
                                _enable = val;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/house.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Home',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/mail.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Inbox',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/notification.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Notifications',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/account.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Account',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/payment.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Payment',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/topup.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Topup',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/withdraw.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Withdraw',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/bills.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Bills & Utilities',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/reports.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Reports',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/transactions.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Transactions',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/reward.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Rewards & Promotions',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/refer.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Refer',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/support.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Support',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/settings.png'),
                              title: Text(
                                'Settings',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/dividinglinedrawer.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        color: Color(0xFFBB0218),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset('assets/logout.png'),
                            title: Text(
                              'Logout',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the current page and the desired result? Its hard to visualize the issue from just the code :)

Comment: Add the screenshots or diagram how you want ? (As said by @RohanThacker)

Comment: Screenshots would be great!

Comment: Added screenshots, I just want the profile part of it static It shouldn't be scrolling when I scroll down for other options in the drawer. Same applies for logout need it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make the drawer as a screen. Give the right side of it as white totally so it will be likely a drawer and rest as a normal screen. Stack the listviews and then `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` will work as intended.
With custom screen there can be many other options as well so you will be having the right thing with slight compromise over the blurriness of actual drawer over the screen which you can also cover but it will be too complex I guess you may try.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the part of code where you want to scroll - "ListView" and add to the "ListView" where you don't want to scroll - "physics: NeverScrollablePhysics()"

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `ListView` widgets for this problem.

**First ListView**, we could use it parent ListView with physics as `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and then you could use **another ListView** inside the parent list view. then you could scroll the child ListView inside the parent ListView.

In addition, You could use the below example.

```
ListView( //Parent ListView with physics as NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap : true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.purple), backgroundColor: Colors.white)),
        ),
        ListView( // scroll child ListView Widget
          shrinkWrap : true,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              child: getDrawerItem(Icons.person, 'Profile'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: getDrawerItem(Icons.history, 'History'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: getDrawerItem(Icons.data_usage, 'Performance'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: getDrawerItem(Icons.beach_access, 'Environments'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Divider(),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                'Log Out',
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0, color: Color(0xFF251756)),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {},
        )
      ],
    );
```

Hope this answer will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I exactly understand what part you want not to scroll but if it is an `AppBar()` then consider using a `CustomScrollView()` (read more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html). In the `slivers` parameter you can then put a `SliverAppBar()` (read more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) which you can pin to the screen or have it change when the user scrolls while staying on scroll or have it scroll with the screen. Underneath, you would then add your a `SliverList()` (read more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html) instead of a `ListView()`.

If this is not what you are looking for then please update your post with screenshots of the current UI and the desired UI.